# About the binary representation

Tags: number-theory

**Problem (Source: China Second Round 2015 (A) Q4)** Find all positive integers $k$ such that for any positive integer $n$, $2^{(k-1)n+1}$ does not divide $\frac{(kn)!}{n!}$.

*I have struggling with this problem and found out a solution in a document.
The author of the solution wrote:*

> The answer is the set of all powers of $2$.
>
> Define $v_p(x)$ such that if $v_p(x) = n$, then $p^n \mid x$ but
> $p^{n+1} \nmid x$. Legendre's Formula gives $v_p(n!) =
> > \dfrac{n-S_p(n)}{p-1}$ where $S_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$
> when written in base $p$. Thus,$$v_2\left(\dfrac{(kn)!}{n!}\right) = (k-1)n+(S_2(n)-S_2(kn)).$$Thus the condition in the question is
> equivalent to $S_2(kn) \geq S_2(n)$. If $k = 1$ then this is trivially
> true. Notice that this is satisfied if and only if $2k$ satisfies it
> as well. Therefore, it suffices to show that there is no such $k > 1$
> which is odd for which $2^{(k-1)n+1}$ does not divide
> $\dfrac{(kn)!}{n!}$ for all $n$.
>
> Let $m$ be a multiple of $k$ with a minimal number of $1$ digits
> (suppose it has $v$ many) and take $m$ to be odd. Then let $m = 2^a+b$
> with $2^a > b$. Notice that the number $w= 2^{a+s\varphi(k)}+b$ is
> also a multiple of $k$ with $v$ ones for every $s \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
>
> We now prove that $w/k$ must have more than $v$ digits $1$ for
> sufficiently large $s$ and so doesn't satisfy the condition of the
> question. Assume otherwise, and pick $s$ so that $w/k$ has at least
> $z$ consecutive zeroes, where $z$ is the length of the of the binary
> representation of $k$. Then for sufficiently large $s$ the number of
> digits $1$ in the binary representation of $w/k \cdot k$ is greater
> than $v$, a contradiction.

There is a part of the solution that seems not really trivial to me:
*" Assume otherwise, and pick $s$ so that $w/k$ has at least $z$ consecutive zeroes, where $z$ is the length of the of the binary
representation of $k$. Then for sufficiently large $s$ the number of
digits $1$ in the binary representation of $w/k \cdot k$ is greater
than $v$, a contradiction. "*

I'm wondering how the number of $1$ in $w$ is effected after we multiply $w/k \cdot k$. Can someone help me figure out this?

Comment: Could I have permission to bump on my post :(